# Diagnosing RegisterWindowsMessage leak

Tags: winapi, resource-leak

We are seeing atom pool resource exhaustion on production servers of one of our applications.

Using the fantastic AtomTableMonitor tool, we've isolated the issue to creation of a huge number of atoms by the RegisterWindowsMessage call.  They all have names like this:

ControlOfs030D000000000270

where the number at the end changes.

My question is:  How do we figure out which process is creating these atoms?

some potential resources:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ntdebugging/2012/01/31/identifying-global-atom-table-leaks/

Comment: Killing them one by one with Task Manager until you hit the evil-doer ought to pay off.  But of course you need to ask this at serverfault.com, the place where people gather that solve these kind of problems.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Atoms that begin with `"ControlOfs..."` are created by Borland/Embarcadero's VCL (Visual Component Library) framework in Delphi/C++Builder.  These atoms are actually in the form of `"ControlOfs<HInstance><ThreadID>"`, where `<HInstance>` and `<ThreadID>` are in hex format (so, in your case, `HInstance = 0x030D0000 = 51183616`, `ThreadID = 0x00000270 = 624`).

There is also another atom name that is created by the VCL, in the form of `"Delphi<ProcessID>"`, where `<ProcessID>` is in hex format.

This means that every instance of an app that uses the VCL creates a new unique `"Delphi..."` atom, and its main UI thread creates a new unique `"ControlOfs..."` atom (these atoms are used to store `TWinControl` object pointers in VCL-created `HWND`s via `SetProp()`, for use by the VCL's `FindControl()` and `IsDelphiHandle()` utility functions).  Both atoms are registered with `GlobalAddAtom()` at app startup, and unregistered at app shutdown with `GlobalDeleteAtom()`, so there is no leak.

However, in Delphi/C++Builder 6 all the way up to RADStudio XE2, there is yet another atom that uses the same `"ControlOfs..."` name.  This atom is created with `RegisterWindowMessage()` (for a private `RM_GetObjectInstance` window message), which cannot be unregistered.  So, every time an affected VCL app is run, this unique atom is created and subsequently leaked.

This was eventually fixed by Embarcadero in RADStudio XE3 in 2012 (Andreas Hausladen posted a [patch](http://andy.jgknet.de/blog/bugfix-units/vclfixpack-10/) for earlier VCL versions).  But pre-existing apps that are compiled with older versions of the VCL are affected, and there is nothing you can do to stop them from leaking without patching them to use a static name with `RegisterWindowMessage()`.

So, to answer your question, using a combination of AtomTableMonitor and Task Manager, you should be able to figure out which apps you are running are VCL apps, and then you can check them individually for leaking atoms.  Or, use [SysInternals Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) with a `Thread Create` filter to get a list of thread IDs and their creating processes over time, then you can match up those thread IDs to the leaked atom names.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a tool like [API Monitor](http://www.rohitab.com/apimonitor) and set it up to track only `RegisterWindowsMessage`. It will show you which process is using this function and a stack trace too (though probably not too useful without symbols).

Also, a quick Google search for `ControlOfs` finds https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?threadID=47678 which matches your issue. They say it's a bug in VCL. Someone posted this fix pack if you have the code:

http://andy.jgknet.de/blog/bugfix-units/vclfixpack-10/

If you don't have the code, I suggest you look for Delphi/VCL applications in your production server and try to update them or report the issue.

Comment: The VCL bug was fixed in RADStudio XE3 in 2012.  Andy's patch is for older versions.  But this only benefits app developers, not app users.  Only the original author of the leaking app will be able to fix it.